# How can I properly identify an identifier?

Tags: scheme, racket

I was thinking any of the following

> (define (ID? x)
>   (symbol? x))

Say I have the following

> (define list '(add 4 5))

I want to simply check if "add" is an identifier or keyword.
So I was considering the following

> (define (ID? x)
>   (char? x))

I was even considering an `and` conditional

> (define (ID? x)
>   (and (char? x)(symbol? x))

But my issue is that for symbol it'll take things such as `@`

and for the `char`? approach it won't accept identifiers with more than one character.

the and approach makes no sense. I'm working off a list so I don't believe `(string? x)` will work since it'll consider the whole list.
Any suggestions would be great. THANK YOU!

Comment: Characters and symbols are different data types, so `(and (char? x) (symbol? x))` is never true.

Comment: Are you implementing an interpreter, and trying to check whether a given symbol is one of the keywords specified by the assignment? If so, you're probably looking for a function like "member"....

Answer (score 2):

Scheme doesn't have a concept of a "keyword" (at least not the type you're talking about; some implementations like Racket and Guile have keywords for keyword arguments, like `#:foo`). Thus, from what I read from your question, anything that's read in as a symbol will be used as an identifier when evaluated. Thus, `symbol?` is sufficient.

If you actually do want to test for Racket keywords, you can use `keyword?`. Such keywords do not pass the `symbol?` test.

```
-> (symbol? 'foo)
#t
-> (keyword? 'foo)
#f
-> (symbol? '#:foo)
#f
-> (keyword? '#:foo)
#t
```